# Getting a 403 when making a POST request to AWS Lightsail Distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, amazon-lightsail

I'm making a POST HTTP request to an AWS Lightsail distribution and am getting a 403 response.  I checked that the distribution's cache allows POST requests (see screenshot below).  GET requests are successful.

[image]

And my cache is set to cache everything:

[image]

Could someone please help resolve this?

Comment: I'm stuck in the same point :-(

Comment: @LuizC turns out that my application (a Spring Boot RESTful API) wasn't handling CORS.  I enabled CORS for all origins using `@CrossOrigin("*")` on all my controllers and everything worked fine :).  Only Chrome logged the error.  If you click on the console log link to the VM, you'll see a short message about their being a CORS error.  CORS is  only applicable if you're calling your back end from a different front end domain.  I hope you figure it out :).